# Application received signal SIGABRT

Tags: ios

```
Application received signal SIGABRT
  (null)
  (
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x36faa8d7 __exceptionPreprocess + 186
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x316781e5 objc_exception_throw + 32
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x36faa7b9 +[NSException raise:format:] + 0
        3   CoreFoundation                      0x36faa7db +[NSException raise:format:] + 34
        4   ktv                                 0x1731f1 _ZNSt11_Deque_baseIsSaIsEE15_M_create_nodesEPPsS3_ + 1411812
        5   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x31c6652f _sigtramp + 38
        6   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x31c5bf5b pthread_kill + 54
        7   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x31c54feb abort + 94
        8   libc++abi.dylib                     0x3492ef6b abort_message + 46
        9   libc++abi.dylib                     0x3492c3f1 _ZL19safe_handler_callerPFvvE + 120
        10  libc++abi.dylib                     0x3492c451 _ZdlPv + 0
        11  libc++abi.dylib                     0x3492d825 __cxa_current_exception_type + 0
        12  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x31678235 objc_exception_rethrow + 12
        13  CoreFoundation                      0x36f00545 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 404
        14  CoreFoundation                      0x36f003a5 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
        15  GraphicsServices                    0x310b6fcd GSEventRunModal + 156
        16  UIKit                               0x32572743 UIApplicationMain + 1090
        17  ktv                                 0xaaa7 _mh_execute_header + 39591
        18  ktv                                 0x37b8 _mh_execute_header + 10168
  )
```

Does anyone know this crash? It is the most crash in my app, but I don't know what caused this. Any help is thanksful.

Comment: SIGABRT can be thrown due to a large number of issues; post your source code

Comment: Symbolication is incorrect. line 17 and 18 should show `main.m`. You might want to check your symbolication process. Also the update the crash reporting library, this most likely is from an armv7s device and your crash reporting lib is not fully compatible.

Comment: Also,provide,please information about the situation and actions, which leed to crash

Comment: But how can I know the really reason about why it crashed? Do I must show the hole crash log?

Answer (score 1):

There is very little that anyone here can say with the information you've provided.

You will need to "symbolicate" the crash log (drag and drop into the organiser in Xcode). This will convert the addresses in the log to files and line numbers in your code. From there you'll be able to see where you're getting an exception thown and hopefully figure out why.

Comment: But what is libsystem_c.dylib and libc++abi.dylib is these are some system libraries? Can I know some thing about the log?